# Where is the source code of pytorch conv2d?

Tags: pytorch

Where do I find the source code of the pytorch function conv2d?

It should be in torch.nn.functional but I only find _add_docstr lines,
if i search for conv2d. I looked here:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/functional.py

Update:
It's is not my typing, I do mean the function.
Conv2d class uses conv2d function from the nn.functional

Here:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/conv.py

On line 338:

```
return F.conv2d(F.pad(input, expanded_padding, mode='circular')
```

F is how they import functional

So then I went there, but I don't find the code.

Comment: [Con2d  is a class](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/0febff36acc4a906ca95a9d39382028b10f92c33/torch/nn/qat/modules/conv.py)

Comment: For those voting to close because "It's **seeking recommendations** for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers." This question is not seeking recommendations in any sense (it's requesting specific information about a library). The question is very clear and is certainly not likely to lead to opinion-based answers so please stop trying to close it for this reason.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The functional code is implemented in C++. As of version 1.13.1 the entry point into the C++ code for `conv2d` is at [aten/src/ATen/native/Convolution.cpp:804](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/v1.13.1/aten/src/ATen/native/Convolution.cpp#L804).

If you are interested more generally in how functions are registered to the API then you can take a look at [aten/src/ATen/native/README.md](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/v1.13.1/aten/src/ATen/native#readme). A deeper dive will benefit from understanding some of the design decisions in PyTorch. For example, the *dispatcher* mechanism ([see here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/wiki/PyTorch-dispatcher-walkthrough)).  More general information can be found in the [PyTorch developer's wiki](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/wiki), though keep in mind this wiki is primarily a tool for contributors and is not as polished as the Python API documentation. IMO a good starting point is the [Core Frontend Onboarding](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/wiki/Core-Frontend-Onboarding) page which gives links to most everything needed to get your head around the PyTorch source code.